# Android native создание двух библиотек cpp

Tags: c++, android-studio, gradle, cmake, android-ndk

Я потихоньку разбираюсь с Android NDK и CMake. Имею следующую структуру проектов:

```
native-cpp
    CMakeLists.txt
    native-lib.cpp
    test.h
    test.cpp
    code
        CMakeLists.txt
        code.h
        code.cpp
```

В Gradle - скрипте я указал путь до файла native-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "../../native-cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
```

Содержимое native-lib/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

project("android") # имя проекта

set(SOURCE_LIB native-lib.cpp test.cpp) # Установка переменной со списком исходников

add_library(native-lib SHARED ${SOURCE_LIB}) # создаем нашу либу

target_include_directories(native-lib PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/code) # для того, чтобы IDE могла найти заголовочные
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/code) #линкуем эту либу к текущей

add_subdirectory(code) # добавляем в поиск еще одну либу

target_link_libraries( native-lib code ) # ссылка на вложенную либу

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

И содержимое native-lib/code/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
    
set(SOURCE_LIB code.cpp)        # Установка переменной со списком исходников

add_library(code STATIC ${SOURCE_LIB}) # Создание статической библиотеки
```

Я ожидаю на выходе две библиотеки: native-lib.so и code.so, чтобы потом их подключить в java - коде:

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
        System.loadLibrary("code");
    }
```

Однако, на выходе я имею только одну библиотеку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно настроить CMake, чтобы генерировалось две библиотеки?

P.S.: я новичок как в NDK, так и в CMake, поэтому критикуйте, если я мыслю не в ту сторону.

Comment: А зачем вам две библиотеки?

Comment: @user7860670 допустим у меня есть несколько проектов, и я хочу сделать эту библиотеку независимой, чтобы цеплять к разным проектам.

Comment: Тогда делайте ее статической и линкуйте. Заодно и размер итоговый подсократится.

Comment: @user7860670 так как я немного не понимаю, задам вопрос: разве я уже не указал, что это будет статическая библиотека? Флаг STATIC указан в add_library

Comment: Ну тогда чем вы недовольны и ожидаете на выходе две .so? В apk же объектные файлы не попадают.

Comment: @user7860670 простите, вы действительно правы! Новое запутало меня, все верно, действительно.